# Link to Goldschmidt discontinuous solutions proof.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

I searched all over the net, but could not find an article which proved the discontinuous jump between the catenary and disc solutions. I found numerous ones, proving the fact that the minimal surface of revolution is a catenary. I am looking for the former type, not the latter. Can someone help?